# Glipper Panel application doesnt load on startup

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard, gnome-panel

I like to use Glipper, a clipboard history remembering Gnome panel application.

But each time my system boots, this application gives an error.

However, if I manually add it after that, it adds itself properly.

How do I configure it to behave properly?

And, oh, the same thing used to happen with both Tomboy and Glipper in Jaunty, and now in karmic, Tomboy seems to work just fine.

Update: There is no error message beyond the simple "Glipper failed to load, Delete, or Dont Delete"

Comment: What error do you get? Have you filed a bug report?

Comment: ...and the error that it gives you is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=458048) (and workaround). I would suggest you to switch to Parcellite (parcellite.sourceforge.net).

Comment: I couldn't get glipper working and use parcellite too.